# Issue while using Modals

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a modal using twitter bootstrap in my application.creating a modal on **onclick event**
It is working fine in firefox and chrome. but while running my application in ie8, inside that modal **NewPage.aspx** page is not getting viewed properly.

here is my code :

```
 <div id="MyModal" class="modal hide in">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    ×</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel">
                   Header</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <iframe id="modal-frame" src="" style="zoom: 0.60; position: relative;" frameborder="0"
                        height="450" width="850"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button modalurl="~/NewPage.aspx" id="lnkNewModal" onclick="openMyModal(this);"
                runat="server">Modal</Button>

   function openMyModal(curObj) {
            $("#MyModal").modal({
                "backdrop": "static",
                "keyboard": true,
                "show": true
            });
            var url = $(curObj).data("modalurl");
            $('#MyModal').on('show', function () {
                $('#modal-frame').attr("src", url);
            });
            $('#MyModal').modal({ show: true });
        }
```

Thank you all in advance for your response.

Comment: is there a problem with you modal or with the page inside the iframe..? how can this code help us helping you?

Comment: Problem is with the page inside the  iframe . In IE Page is not displaying properly inside that iframe.

Answer (score 2):

You have a slight error in the Javascript code

```
function openMyModal(curObj) {       

 var url = $(curObj).attr("modalurl");    //Note here

            $('#MyModal').on('show', function () {
                $('#modal-frame').attr("src", url);
            });            
            $("#MyModal").modal({
                "backdrop": "static",
                "keyboard": true,
                "show": true
            });            
        }
```

this works perfectly , Cheers!!!

Comment: This works perfectly in fire fox and chrome . but in internet explorer, modal size is same but  i-frame size is 100 x 100 . when i try to keep my mouse over it, it immediately vanishes .